# Can any private key information be exposed when signing an email?

Tags: encryption, email, pgp, openpgp

So I know that PGP encrypted email can be vulnerable to a known-plaintext attack from a known, consistant email footer or greeting (“Hello”, “Yours truly, xxx”, etc), but does the same thing apply to PGP signatures on an email?

If I always PGP sign my emails, and all my emails end with “From, [name]”, can any of my secret PGP information be exposed?

Comment: For a signature, the plain text is known **by design**. If having the plaintext *m* and the signature of *m* with the private key *p* would allow one to deduce *p*, then that signature scheme would be completely broken by design.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: no.**

**Longer answer:** If your PGP encryption is vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks, then that means PGP is using an old broken cipher. Modern, non-broken crypto (with updated software) will not have vulnerabilities like this. You can encrypt or sign whatever you want and no secret key information will be revealed.